# Como efetuar a busca pelo button e os filtros aparecerem corretos

Tags: c#

Bom dia, estou com um problema para realizar filtros em um `DataGridView` com um botão de busca, toda vez que filtro diretamente pelo botão ele me mostra corretamente todos os valores, porem se eu clico no campo e vou filtrar, a funcionalidade vai, porem, a coluna função fica com os valores invisíveis.

[Grid com filtro geral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m1rn.png)
[Grid com filtro especifico](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Mjo.png)

`Codigo`

```
   private void btnProcurar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       lista.Text = "";
       lista.Rows.Clear();

       string sqlConnection = @"Data Source=ALPHA-DESKTOP;Initial Catalog=BancoProjetos;Integrated Security=True";
       SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection);

       try
       {
           string usuarios = "SELECT * FROM Tab_Usuarios";
           string valor = txtProcurar.Text;

           if (txtProcurar.Text != "")
           {
               usuarios = "SELECT idusuario, nome, email, funcao  FROM Tab_Usuarios WHERE idusuario LIKE @valor OR nome LIKE @valor OR email LIKE @valor OR funcao LIKE @valor ";                }

           DataTable dados = new DataTable();
           SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(usuarios, conexao);
           adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valor", "%" + txtProcurar.Text + "%");

           conexao.Open();
           adaptador.Fill(dados);

           foreach (DataRow linha in dados.Rows)
           {
               lista.Rows.Add(linha.ItemArray);
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           throw;
       }
   }
```